# Is this grammar ambiguous?

Tags: formal-grammars, parsers, ambiguity

I have the grammar:

$\qquad \begin{align}
 S &\to S = P \mid S \neq P \mid P  \\
 P &\to NUM
\end{align}$

This grammar suffers from left recursion. To eliminate left recursion, I got:

$\qquad \begin{align}
 S &\to PS' \\
 S' &\to\, = PS' \mid\, \neq PS' \mid \varepsilon \\
 P &\to NUM
\end{align}$

However when constructing the LL(1) parsing table, it turns out the grammar is ambiguous. Is there a way to disambiguate the grammar without changing the generated language, or did I make a mistake somewhere?

This is my work so far:

```
Non-terminal Nullable First            Follow
S            False    NUM              $
    S'           True     !=, ==, epsilon  $
P            False    NUM              $, ==, !=

Parse Table
     !=       ==    NUM      $
S                   ->PS'
S'  ->!=PS'  ->==PS'        ->epsilon
P                   ->NUM
```

Comment: Are my workings correct then?

Comment: I don't see how the grammar is ambiguous. Can you give a case where it is?

Comment: Look up refactoring ambiguous grammars. There should be enough material on google to get you started.

Comment: ninjagecko: Aren't there conflicting entries for S' in the parse table?

Comment: @barq: Ambiguity is a property of the grammer and not the parser. You did not state what sort of topdown parser you were using. Even if you did, I would probably be unfamiliar with it. But since ambiguity is a property of the grammar and not the parser, it shouldn't matter if you can construct a sentence that is ambiguous with the grammar. The only sentences I can seem to construct are like `34 != 12 == 55` which seem fairly unambiguous (`S(P(34) S'(!= P(12)) S'(== P(55)))`).

Comment: I'm using LL(1) for parsing. I edited in your simplification above. 

The parse table also contained a mistake. I've corrected it now.  
 
That way there are no ambiguities in the grammar.

Comment: If there are multiply defined entries in the table, it's not LL(1). It could be due to left-recursion, the need for a left-factored grammar, or ambiguity (even after resolving the previous conditions). A parse table isn't going to necessarily tell you whether your grammar is ambiguous, although a multiply defined entry may hint that it is. As mentioned, if the grammar is ambiguous, it's ambiguous, but from what I can tell the grammar isn't ambiguous. Also, your follow sets are incomplete. FOLLOW(S') = FOLLOW(S) = {$}.

Comment: The grammar is not ambiguous. This is demonstrated by your parsing table: each table cell has at most one production in it.

Answer (score 1):

We can consider $NUM$ and therewith $P$ a terminal symbol. Furthermore, $S$ does only occur once in every derivation. Therefore, if there is any ambiguity, it has to stem from

$\qquad \displaystyle S' \to\, = PS' \mid\, \neq PS' \mid \varepsilon$

Now, that fragment is a [right-regular](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar) grammar with only one non-terminal whose right-hand sides do not share any prefixes. So clearly every term has only derivation, given by its length and permutation of $=$ and $\neq$.

In total, your grammar is unambiguous. Above observations also suggest that the grammar can be parsed in one pass from left to right with one token lookahead (distinguish $=$ and $\neq$). In fact, the grammar is basically a deterministic (no shared prefixes) and right-regular (replace all $P$ with $NUM$) grammar, so it's certainly an LL(1) grammar.

So I suggest you revisit the construction of the parsing table (your favorite textbook or [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser#Constructing_an_LL.281.29_parsing_table)) -- you must have made a mistake.